# Вечный цикл InputStream.read() != -1

Tags: java

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isConnected()) {
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
                try {
                    int b;
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                            socket.getInputStream());
                    while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
                        buf.put((byte) b);
                        System.out.println((byte) b);
                    }
                    System.out.println("readed");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int id = buf.getInt();
                System.out.println("Packet id " + id);
                if (id == 0)
                    return;
                Packet packet = getProtocol().getPacketById(id);
                packet.onRead(new NetBufIn(buf));
                for (PacketAdapter adapter : adapters) {
                    adapter.onPacketReceive(packet);
                }
            }
        }

    }).start();
```

Цикл while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {} почему-то длится вечно, и доходит до System.out.println("readed"); только после закрытия соединения с сокетом, в чём проблема? что я не так делаю?
Код отправки пакета

```
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    int id = getProtocol().getId(packet.getClass());
    buf.putInt(id);
    packet.onWrite(new NetBufOut(buf));
    for (PacketAdapter adapter : adapters) {
        adapter.onPacketSend(packet);
    }
    try {
        buf.flip();
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            socket.getOutputStream().write(buf.get());
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
        buf.clear();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Потому что сокет - это условно-бесконечный поток, который не считается завершенным, пока подключение не закрыто?

Comment: А как тогда считывать переданный пакет?

Comment: Закрыть сокет при завершении отправки данных, не?

Comment: @МихаилИванов, обычно у пакета есть четкая структура, в которой в одном из начальных полей можно прочесть длину payload'а, а между ними еще добавляют null-паддинги, чтобы в случае получения битого пакета можно было сориентироваться и вовремя обнаружить следующий. На основании этого умудрялись даже wi-fi атаки делать, вставляя конец пакета, куда нужно и начиная передавать свой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы неверно понимаете работу протокола TCP. Работая с этим протоколом, надо вообще забыть про такую вещь, как пакеты.

Если вы отправляете с сервера 100 байт - это не означает, что на клиент придет 100 байт. Драйвер TCP на сервере может задержать отправку этих 100 байт, чтобы склеить со следующими. А может, напротив, отправить только половину, если считает что 100 - это слишком много. Оставшуюся половину он отправит позже, когда клиент прочитает первую порцию.

И на клиенте тоже самое. Драйвер будет добавлять все пришедшие данные во внутренний буфер приема до тех пор, пока вы их не прочитаете.

Протокол TCP предоставляет вам абстракцию двух потоков данных - от клиента к серверу и от сервера к клиенту. Каждый из этих потоков передает данные до тех пор, пока не будет закрыт на стороне отправителя. Не существует никаких способов определить границы между отдельными операциями записи в поток на стороне сервера.

Если вам надо организовать передачу данных в виде некоторых порций с хорошо различимыми границами между ними - то это называется уже "*сообщение*" (message), а не "пакет". Для разбиение потока на сообщения есть два способа:

- указание длины каждого сообщения перед ним,
- фиксированный размер сообщений.

В обоих случаях все сводится к тому, что получатель знает, когда сообщение заканчивается.

---

Теперь совет по вашему коду:

На стороне отправителя. Сначала сдвиньте в буфере текущую позицию на 4 (к примеру, сделав `putInt(0)`) - еще перед записью остальных данных в буфер. После записи в буфер всех данных, вернитесь к началу и положите в буфер актуальное количество данных:

```
buf.flip();
buf.putInt(0, buf.limit());
while (buf.hasRemaining())...
```

На стороне приемника. Сначала считайте первые 4 байта. Сформируйте из них int и вы узнаете, сколько всего байт в этом сообщении.