# Неправильное магическое число в заголовке GZip. Передача должна идти в поток GZip

Tags: c#, многопоточность, сокет, gzip

Задача: 2 клиента должны отсылать сжимать на лету массив байт, отсылать его, принимать массив байт, распаковывать и воспроизводить его (я отсылаю аудио).

Метод, в котором происходит передача:

```
private static void AsiooutOnAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    audio = SamplesToBytes(monoSamples); 
    byte[] compressedBytes = CompressBytes(audio);

    if (_isConnected)
    {
        Task.Run(() => _receiver.BeginSend(compressedBytes, 0, compressedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, SendCallback, null));
    }
}
```

Получение:

```
private static void Receive()
{
    _receiver.BeginReceive(incomingBytes, 0, incomingBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveCallback, null);
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int receivedBytesCount = _receiver.EndReceive(ar);
    byte[] _audio = new byte[receivedBytesCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < receivedBytesCount; i++)
    {
        _audio[i] = incomingBytes[i];
    }
    var decompressBytes = DecompressBytes(_audio);
    _incomingBuffer.AddSamples(decompressBytes, 0, decompressBytes.Length);
    Receive();
}
```

Сжатие и распаковка:

```
public static byte[] CompressBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            gzip.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        return output.ToArray();
    }
}

static byte[] DecompressBytes(byte[] gzip)
{
    using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        int size = gzip.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int count = 0;
            do
            {
                count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size); //ошибка появляется тут
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0);
            return memory.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Используете tcp или udp?

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453374/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-inputstream-read-1/453385#453385

Comment: @PavelMayorov, TCP. Понял. Спасибо.