# Объединение массивов байтов

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Есть необходимость присоединять один массив байт к другому (много раз подряд).

Для этого я нашел пока 2 варианта:

1. объединение через `arr.CopyTo(..);` либо `Array.Copy(...);`
2. объединение через `StreamWriter` (то есть пишем байты в поток, потом все вместе считываем)

Может, есть другие способы?

Линковский `Concat`, думаю, будет долго выполняться.

Про `theList.AddRange()` я вообще молчу.

Есть ли еще способы?

Важно быстродействие.

**UPD:**

Если я делаю так

```
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
{
  var sendBuff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(i.ToString());
  theNetwork.Write(sendBuff, 0, sendBuff.Length);
}
```

То на входе вот таким способом

```
var resp = new byte[0];
var partSize = 1024;
do
{
    var subBuff = new byte[partSize];
    var bytesCount = client.GetStream().Read(subBuff, 0, partSize);
    var temp = resp;
    resp = new byte[resp.Length + bytesCount];
    temp.CopyTo(resp, 0);
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(subBuff, 0, resp, temp.Length, bytesCount);
} while (client.GetStream().DataAvailable);
var s = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(resp);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

я рассчитываю получить строку

> 0123456789101112...99

а вместо этого она обрывается на 40-50 где-то

То есть чтобы получить остальные данные, мне снова нужно снова запустить цикл приема. Но вот вопрос, а что, если отдающая сторона одновременно отдает с разных потоков разную информацию? Тогда я могу получить что-то вроде

> 012345678910еще какая то хрень1112...99

Но, TCP обещает доставить пакеты в том порядке, в котором они были отправлены. поэтому, если я передам один объект целиком, он и придет целиком. Поэтому мне нужно отправлять цельный массив

Comment: `AddRange` внутри себя вполне те же самые `Array.Copy` и `arr.CopyTo` использует

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но — зачем? Если вам нужно массивное копирование данных, возможно, вы что-то делаете не так.

Comment: @VladD, мне нужно очень быстро сериализовать класс и отправить по сети. Только данные, без лишнего, поэтому не хочу использовать BinaryFormatter. Я перегоняю свойства в byte[] при помощи BitConverter, но мне нужно очень быстро объединить полученные массивы байт в один большой массив.

Comment: @iRumba: А почему тогда не просто собрать коллекцию массивов, и отправить их один за одним через обыкновенный цикл `for`? Какой у вас типичный размер куска? Возможно, вы подходите к проблеме не с той стороны.

Comment: @VladD, я об этом думал, но это нарушит целостность сообщения. По моим наблюдениям, после второй запись в NetworkStream данные уже отправляются и приходят получателю. А это несвязанные данные, я не соберу из них целую картину, если не добавлять к каждому отправляемому массиву какой то идентификатор (а это накладные расходы). Поэтому в theNetwokStream.Write(...) надо пихать данные целиком. А для этого надо иметь монолитный массив, а не массив массивов. Если у вас есть иной способ это сделать, поделитесь им пожалуйста.

Comment: @iRumba: Не, подождите, что-то не то. Получатель в любом случае не имеет права рассчитывать, что он прочитает данные одним куском, он должен вычитывать их в цикле. Поэтому писать данные по кусочкам — это нормально.

Comment: @VladD, я дополнил вопрос. Там пояснение к тому что вы говорите

Comment: @iRumba вы ошибаетесь, думая что то, что вы записываете, является пакетом.

Comment: @iRumba протокол TCP вообще не дает доступа верхним уровням к отдельным пакетам

Comment: @iRumba на самом деле, ваша проблема - вот тут: `while (client.GetStream().DataAvailable)`

Comment: @iRumba так нельзя делать. Совсем нельзя...

Comment: @iRumba вот мой старый ответ про TCP (правда, там язык другой - но смысл тот же самый): http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453385/178779

Comment: @iRumba: Согласен с предыдущим оратором: `DataAvailable` пользоваться нельзя. Вам нужно знать длину сообщения и читать из потока до тех пор, пока не прочитаете сколько нужно.

Comment: Вот ещё по теме: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я и не называл сообщение пакетом. Отнюдь, я опроверг сказанное владом тем, что показал, как в абстракции TCP уходят сообщения записанные в стрим. А чем DataAvailable не устроил. Я, кстати, способ такой с МСДНа взял. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.dataavailable(v=vs.110).aspx Там говорят, что свойство это показывает есть ли в потоке данные.

Comment: @VladD, согласен, что надо знать длину сообщения. Но не совсем. Я просто считываю данные. Сообщение у меня имеет заголовок и тело. В общем из набора полученных байтов я прекрасно могу выделить все сообщения.

Comment: В любом случае, вы оба тут учите меня получать сообщение. Спасибо, конечно, за ценные замечания, но у меня по отправке вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разу уж вопрос подняли новым ответом - проблема не в склейке массивов, а в том, что вот это предположение неверно:

> TCP обещает доставить пакеты в том порядке, в котором они были отправлены. поэтому, если я передам один объект целиком, он и придет целиком. Поэтому мне нужно отправлять цельный массив"

Пакет - это не то что "записали в сокет одним вызовом", это именно пакет TCP. Никаких гарантий, что записанное одним вызовом в сокет уйдет именно одним пакетом, нет. Даже наоборот - при достаточно большом объеме данных они скорее всего дойдут разными пакетами.

Поэтому нет никакого надежного  способа писать в сокет из нескольких потоков одновременно, с гарантией получения осмысленного результата на другой стороне.

Придется или для каждого потока открывать свой сокет, или запись в сокет из нескольких потоков пропускать через общий поток-диспетчер.

И даже в этом случае с каждым сообщением нужно сначала отправлять его длину, а потом уже данные - иначе на получающей стороне не будет надежного способа узнать об окончании получения одного сообщения (и о начале получения следующего).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно пометить блок кода, как Unsafe и ручками через указатели манипулировать массивом.
Я думаю, что это самый быстрый вариант.

Вот тут уже провели тесты, которые подтверждают мои слова:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099604/any-faster-way-of-copying-arrays-in-c

Comment: и по той же ссылке: _memcpyimpl is fastest, but it's not necessarily worth worrying about._

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать

```
List<bite> combList = new List<bite>();

combList.AddRange(Arr1);
combList.AddRange(Arr2);
...
combList.AddRange(ArrN);
```

То есть фактически держишь вместо аррея -- лист. И в него добавляешь уже поблочно те мелкие Арреи.

А когда тебе нужен полный аррей вместо листа:

```
var rez = combList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил использовать `MemoryStream`, вместо отдельных массивов:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
// записываем данные используя BinaryWriter:
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode, true)) {
    writer.Write(some_data);
}
// обрезаем лишнее (память в MemoryStream выделяется с запасом):
stream.Capacity = (int)stream.Length;
// и вот он, готовый массив, доступен через метод GetBuffer:
byte[] data = stream.GetBuffer();
```